# Adding objects to the "? extends" type of Generic Collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

```
public void addAllAnimals(ArrayList<? extends Animal> animalLikeList){

 // I need to add animal objects (eg Dog, Cat that extends Animal) to animalLikeList.

}
```

I know that it doesn't allow to add directly since `? extends Animal` stands for unknown sub type of the `Animal`. 
My question is : Isn't there any way (indirect way) to `add` or `addAll` an `Animal` or a SubType of `Animal` object to the `animalLikeList` ?

Comment: I editted it Akhil. I wanna know is there any way (any naughty way) to add elements to it. Or it is really IMPOSSIBLE!

Comment: Why do you use the wildcard if you intend to violate its restriction, it just makes no sense?

Comment: I am passing different animal lists(ArrayList<Cat>, ArrayList<Dog>) to the addAllAnimals method. That's why I am using addAllAnimals(ArrayList<? extends Animal>

Comment: Then how can you be sure you will not be committing heap pollution if you add a Cat to a List of Dogs? That's the whole purpose of the wildcard restriction in this case. It's there to protect your data and you wanting to violate it indicates something is not right IMHO

Comment: Got your point now Edwin.+1 and Agreed!

Comment: You can use non generic collection to addAll

public void testExtends(ArrayList<? extends Parent> list) throws Exception {
 /* list.add(new Child());
  list.add(new Parent());
  list.add(new GrandParent());
  // can not add
  */
  /**
   * Unsafe collection way
   */
  ArrayList list2=new ArrayList();
  list.addAll(list2);
 }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no direct legal way (apart from unsafe type casts). You can only add elements to a generic collection declared with `super`, not `extends`. This may be easier to remember with the acronym *PECS* (Producer - Extends, Consumer - Super), popularized by Josh Bloch in *Effective Java, 2nd Edition*, Item 28.

In fact what you seem to be after doesn't seem to make direct sense. A `List<? extends Animal>` can be e.g. a `List<Dog>` or a `List<Cat>`. The former can only accept `Dog` elements, the latter only `Cat`s. And since you can't instantiate generic (nonreifiable) types in Java, you must know at runtime that you are dealing with a list of dogs, so you only attempt to add dogs to it (and vice versa for cats). That means you can't locally and statically create the objects to be added - you must get them in a generic way too, and moreover in a way which allows the compiler to ensure that the concrete types match each time. The simplest way for this is to pass the element(s) as a generic parameter. So it is possible and safe to do this:

```
public <E extends Animal> void addAllAnimals(List<E> animalLikeList, E animal) {
    animalLikeList.add(animal);
}

List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();

addAllAnimals(dogs, new Dog());
addAllAnimals(cats, new Cat());
```

Note that this method is generic, with a named type parameter, which ensures that the actual generic type of the list is the same as the element type to be added to it.

You can trivially replace the `E` parameter with a `Collection<E>` to add several objects at once.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is : Isn't there any way (indirect way) to add or addAll an Animal or a SubType of Animal object to the animalLikeList ?

Not without changing the signature, and for good reason. Suppose you want to add `Dog` values to that list... but suppose it's logically a list of cats:

```
ArrayList<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
addAllAnimals(cats);
```

You shouldn't be able to add a `Dog` to an `ArrayList<Cat>`, should you?

If you want to be able to add *any* type of animal to the list, you need:

```
public void addAllAnimals(ArrayList<Animal> animalLikeList) {
```

or

```
public void addAllAnimals(ArrayList<? super Animal> animalLikeList) {
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. But I am passing different animal lists(ArrayList<Cat>, ArrayList<Dog>) to the addAllAnimals method. That's why I am using addAllAnimals(ArrayList<? extends Animal>.

Comment: @NamalFernando: Then how are you expecting to add a `Dog` to the list within `addAllAnimals`? What do you *want* to happen if you try to add a `Dog` to an `ArrayList<Cat>`? Do you see how you've got a fundamental problem there?

Comment: @NamalFernando Jon has pretty much said all there is to say on this matter. There is no safe way to add to a list with that kind of a type.

Comment: Yep Jon and Jarkko. I'm totally agree with you. What I wanted to know is "is there any way of adding an Animal or a SubType of Animal object to the animalLikeList ? in the above mentioned way or another. +1 for your points and nice explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply change the method signature to use an invariant type parameter?

```
public void addAllAnimals(ArrayList<Animal> animalLikeList){
   animalLinkedList.add(new Dog());
   animalLinkedList.add(new Cat());

}
```

It should work just fine, and by using an invariant type parameter you will be allowed to read from the list or write into it, and by the rules of subtype pollymorphism it can contain any kind of animal that you want.

Instead of trying to pass list of dogs or list of cats, pass list of animals to the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArraList<anything extends animal> list= new ArrayList<anything extends animal>();


addAllAnimals(list);
```

This is perfectly valid. your method `addAllAnimals` will accept any arrayList which declares to contain any sub-type of Animal.

and for addition an object/List, you can any object/list which subtype of Animal.

Comment: I don't think this would even compile

Comment: well, in place of "anything extends animal" there may dog, cat etc. Idont't see any reason why it will not compile

Answer (score 0):

Not in a typesafe way...

One idea would be to change the signature to:

```
public static <T extends Animal> void addAllAnimals(ArrayList<? super T> list){}
```

where you could add T or subtypes of T to a list of T...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non generic way to addAll in a generic collection

```
public void testExtends(ArrayList<? extends Parent> list) throws Exception {
    /*  list.add(new Child());
        list.add(new Parent());
        list.add(new GrandParent());
        // can not add
        */
        /**
         * Unsafe collection way
         */
        ArrayList list2=new ArrayList();
        list.addAll(list2);
    }
```